# jGraphx - edges overlapping vertices and other edges after moving vertex

Tags: java, jgraphx

After I do the layout in my jgraphx based application the graph looks nice without having edges and vertices overlapped.

[Graph after the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4xOu.jpg)

However, when I move the vertex to new position, the edge start to overlap other vertices and edges.

[Graph after moving vertex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz8TA.jpg)

What can be done to avoid such behavior? Is there some property to define in order to avoid overlapping?

The tools like Visio, after you move vertex, they reorganizing edges so nothing is overlapped. I would expect such behavior to be implemented by jgraphx?

Thanks for any help or hint!

Comment: For what I have seen so far, you can have a "freely modifiable" layout, or use some programmatic layout (e.g. mxCompactTree) but in this case the layout is mostly entirely automatic: I mean that you can resize vertexes but they're going to always be arranged as a tree, no matter how much you move them around. So,it's not exactly Visio-like.

Comment: Try `mxGraph.setResetEdgesOnMove(true)`.